# How do I view images embedded into a wiki on Wiki Server 4 (OS X 10.9.5) on other computers?

Tags: graphics, server.app

A group I am a part of uses Wiki Server 4 to share information. Recently, I've found that when I upload/embed images from my computer onto a Wiki Page, those same images are not visible on other computers (even within the same browser - Safari).

Is there anything I can do so that embedded images are visible within a wiki page for all users on different computers (and different operating systems - Windows 7 verse OS X)?

Comment: What errors does the console in the browser say?

Comment: This is probably really showing my ignorance, but what exactly do you mean by console? Any specific instructions on where I can find these errors?

Comment: Press ⌥⌘C to show the console and and refresh the page—any errors should be shown in the console log.